# Laravel Inertia rendering data from backend to frontend

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

Totally new to using reactJS with laravel inertia.

I am trying to render the data from my database to the front end. I use a controller to get the data from the database by using...

```
// Show all main categories
public static function index() {
    return MainCategory::all(['main_category_id', 'main_category_name']);
}
```

then passing it to the frontend using the `web.php` by using the following code.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return Inertia::render('Admin/Categories', [
        'categories' => MainCategoryController::index()
   ]);
})->name('admin.category-setup');
```

I currently do not know how to call `categories` in the front end using reactjs.
How can I do that?

Comment: Looks like you have to better read the docs before you start working. Laravel and Inertia have a very good documentation that explains it all. First, you should learn the basics of the framework & library. Your question suggests that you are not clear on how they work...
But taking into account your code, you should have React receiving the `categories` as props, see docs here: https://inertiajs.com/pages#creating-pages

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes approach the accessing of passed props by using Inertia's inbuilt `usePage`-Hook for React. This comes in handy when you are working with shared data that you have made accessible for all of the frontend components (https://inertiajs.com/shared-data). As long as your Backend (Laravel) Code works properly and the actual `categories`-Property is handed over to the Categories-Component or shared for all of the frontend, you could do something like this:

```
import React from 'react';    
import { usePage } from '@inertiajs/inertia-react';
    
    function App() {
        const categories = usePage().props.categories;
    
        return (
            <ul>
                {categories.map((category) =>
                    (<li>{category}</li>))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

The most common practice for me however is to simply give the same variable names that you pass in Laravel into the Inertia-Component into the React-Component-Props like this. To me it looks like that should perfectly work with your Use-Case:

```
import React from 'react';    
    
    function App({categories}) {        
        return (
            <ul>
                {categories.map((category) =>
                    (<li>{category}</li>))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
```

If you want to find more about Inertia, I highly recommend to go through the docs. The developers did a great job in explaining everything so that an unexperienced Laravel and React Dev could understand what is going on. It is actually not much to read but shows some interesting features:
https://inertiajs.com/